# bootstrap 3 - hover effect on autoloop video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put hovering effect on a autoloop video such as this website - http://campaign.mcdonalds.com.tw/McCafe/ does

[this part of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYdJE.png)

Before hovering, the autoloop video is having an overlay.

When hovering, the overlay will disappear and the video will enlarge a little bit.

How can I achieve this hovering effect?

Comment: check `border` and `outline` - i think one of them disappears on hover. also check `padding` and `margin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some CSS magic:

```css
.vid-container {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#c90;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  position:relative;
}

.vid-container::after {
  content: " ";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}


.vid-container:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}

.vid-container:hover::after {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-container">
  Your video here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This what I need :D

Comment: @HansonLi I just updated my answer, there is a flaw.

Comment: @HansonLi I added the `pointer-event` to allow user to select the element. But if you don't want the user to interact with it, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/wcbxanpd/1/) for you showing you how to use the scale property to scale your video up or down and also how you can control the opacity of the video.

**HTML:**

```
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ie-C7DQVNKw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**css:**

```
iframe {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

iframe:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
}
```

**Explanation:**

So, I am doing two things here:

1. For normal state I am using the transform property to scale the video to 1,1 which is optional and not needed but still I kept it to for you to understand.

And when I hover over the div the iframe is scaled to (1.1 , 1.1)  which means 10% increase in size in both x and y direction.

2. For hover state I have applied opacity to the iframe.